# Why do the components loaded by using WMS and WFS from GeoServer not the same?

Tags: geoserver, wms, wfs

I have tried to load shape files into GeoServer, but by loading into QGIS, the WMS and WFS versions are not the same. The WMS version seems like correct. They are both loaded by using WGS84. Do you have any suggestions?

[image: The green rectangles are from the WFS version, while the blue border ones are from WMS version.]

Comment: Could you provide some more information about the shapefile? What is the CRS?  Is it a raw shapefile or it is stored in a DB?  What is the current projection of the qGIS dataframe, also WGS84?

Comment: For both layer are using WGS84 in QGIS.

Comment: the shp file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B78KovfaygFDQ0xaZTN4dXk5ZUk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Harold, package the entire shapefile into a folder (containing shx, shp, dbf, and prj if there is one).  Then place that on your Google Drive.

Comment: Thanks. The file is at https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B78KovfaygFDOW9Ea016RmFpZjA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: When loading the shapefile into GeoServer, both WMS and WFS services render the same in qGIS 2.0.1.  I was not able to duplicate the issue.